# Checking the successor of natural number

Tags: coq

I want to prove  a goal  and I have two hypothesis.
Could you help me in proving the goal? Thank you very much for your help.
`Goal : (S m <? S m - (S m - 1)) = true` with two hypothesis

```
m : nat
H : 1 < 1
H0 : (S  m =? 0) = false
```

Answer (score 2):

1 is not, in fact, less than 1. Therefore, we can prove absurdity. Good thing, too, since the goal itself is otherwise impossible.

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
contradict H. (* now proving ~(1 < 1) *)
(* Well, < is irreflexive: forall x, ~(x < x). *)
apply Nat.le_irrefl.
```